# How to highlight UIBarButton when touched in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to highlight UIBarButton when touched  is it possible if so please help me.

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshAction)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton;
[leftBarButton release];
```

Thank You
Praveena

Comment: Mh I tried out your code and the button does get highlighted for me. See [here](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/6863/highlight.jpg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highlighting when touched is the behaviour of *UIButton*. It has a propery **showsTouchWhenHighlighted**, when set to *YES* shows white flash when touched. So, you can't make *UIBarButtonItem* behave it like that.

You can create a *UIButton*, enable *showsTouchWhenHighlighted*, and  add it to a *UIBarButtonItem*.

```
UIButton *btn;
// Create and configure the UIButton
btn.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
UIBarButtonItem *barBtn = [UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
// Configure and add the UIBarButtonItem
```

Answer (score 0):

see this,

Apple documentation

```
UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
Glows when tapped. The default item style.
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared in UIBarButtonItem.h
```

it may helps you.